# Adding special characters to Python regex engine

Tags: python

I have a project for searching for bytecode instructions and I would like to expand it to allow the use of Regular Expressions for matching patterns.

The gist of what I want to do is have custom character classes/sets so I can have something such as `ISTORE` match any of the following instructions:

`ISTORE` `ISTORE_0` `ISTORE_1` `ISTORE_2` `ISTORE_3`

And then something similar for `ILOAD` ... `ILOAD_n` etc.

ISTORE and ILOAD would be similar to metacharacters like `\s` where they truly stand for multiple characters.

Basically I am just looking for a jumping off point so I can find a way to implement my own metacharacters.

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to match with regex ?

Comment: What do you have now? Are you just looking for a regex tutorial? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: "I am just looking for a jumping off point so I can find a way to implement my own special characters." I want to be able to use "ISTORE" in a regular expression in Python and have it match ISTORE, ISTORE_0 ... ISTORE_n just how \s will match whitespace.

I am very familiar with writing regexes, however I have never tried to mess with the engine itself.

Comment: As I understand it you want ISTORE in an expression to be treated as something like `ISTORE(_\d)?` or `(ISTORE_0|ISTORE_1|ISTORE_2|ISTORE_3|ISTORE)`.  You are asking how to extend the actual regex engine to handle this, rather than add a preprocessing search and replace step.

Comment: You cannot add metacharacters to the regex engine, no. You'll have to just use normal regular expression patterns.

Comment: @vossad01, yes that is exactly what I mean. I want to extend the regex engine.

Comment: @kstev you really really really _don't_ want to extend the regex engine. We are just saving you time by letting you know before you try it and find out for yourself.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.  Burning a flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify the regex engine (which would be quite difficult)

You just need a helper function to convert your flavour of regex to python's in the same way that you use `re.escape`

```
def my_re_escape(regex):
    regex = re.escape(regex)
    regex = regex.replace('foo', 'bar')
    # etc
    return regex
```

Comment: It's not a flavor of regex though. It's metacharacters. Considering there are 205 opcodes in Java bytecode this really doesn't sound appealing to me to just have a find and replace method.

Comment: Preprocessing the regex is also recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1922324/2036917

Comment: So I should make it replace ISTORE with  (ISTORE_0|ISTORE_1|ISTORE_2|ISTORE_3|ISTORE) every time? Sounds incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @kstev, You would replace `ISTORE` with `ISTORE_\d+`

Comment: @kstev are 205 search and replace rules, any worse than 205 rules to teach a regex engine in that respect?  Concerning performance, yes I imagine a custom regex engine could be more efficient than a string replace, but have you determined this is so performance critical that it is worth the additional effort?